# Is it optimal to use UI Canvas for a 2D platformer background?

Tags: unity, optimization, unity-ui

Using UI Panel component is convenient in the sense that the panel will always be stretched to the size of the screen at any resolution, unlike a sprite (in simple mode) the size of which depends on the texture import. I'm not considering the sprite scaling because it may affect performance, but doesn't the panel work the same way?

Comment: Scaling is a multiplication, one of the cheapest operations a processor can do. If you're trying to improve performance, this is not the thing you should be worried about. Try running a profiler on your current implementation to check whether it's performing within your target range, and if it's not, to isolate the bottleneck that's holding it back. Then you can ask for help solving that bottleneck.

Comment: I just read somewhere in the Unity docs that scaling is not optimal, that raised my question. And, yes, I'm trying to do a premature optimization here.

Comment: If you can cite that specific source, we can dig onto what kind of optimality it's describing and whether or not that's a significant concern for a background image.

Comment: Profile before you optimize. Otherwise you would just be wasting time and effort.

Comment: I agree: since in general this is not considered a bad practice, then it's ok. @DMGregory
I can't remember the source. I only remember that it was said that objects meshes  should not be scaled to match the dimension of the game because it can impact performance, instead they should initially have a suitable size.

Comment: If they're talking about meshes then the concern may have been about non-uniform scaling or scaling of physics objects, neither of which appears to be relevant to your current situation.